# Determine that URL will / have been redirected to a different URL programmatically

Tags: java, redirect, http-status-codes

I need to download a bunch of apks from a market. Analyze each file if it contains ads inside using Multi-apk tool and compress it again (This is not the issue so I won'd discuss it any further)

Right now, I'm doing the part wherein I will download apk from a particular market. I get the source code of the page and get all URLS that ends with .APK

After each URL is extracted from the page, I download it using commons io. However, whenever a download is complete, I noticed that all of them is the same in size. Which makes me think that it is downloading the same file.

Later on, I realized that I am being redirected to a different URL.

What I want to do is to determine if the URL is redirecting me to a different URL.

I tried getting the response code of that URL, it's giving me 200 but when I'm already connected, it will redirect me later on to a different page.

Here's the code that I used to try to check the response code of the URL.

```
boolean urlValidity =true;
try
{
    URLConnection urlConn = new URL(url).openConnection();
    String RC = urlConn.getHeaderField(0);
    System.out.println("RC " + RC);
    if ( (RC == null) || (!(RC.contains("200"))) )
    {

        urlValidity = false;
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    return false;
}
return urlValidity;
```

I need to do this so I wont need to continue to download the APK of that URL.
Is there a way to fix this programmatically?

Comment: HttpURLConnection has `setInstanceFollowRedirects(false)` to stop it from following 30x redirects automatically, would that help?

Comment: @Ian I dont know yet. But I'll try to use this and see if it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `setInstanceFollowRedirects` to false to ensure you dont get redirected. This will also download very less content from the connection that you make.
I recently had a project where I had to find how many hops does a URL make to reach the final URL and could use the LongURL API.

Comment: Assuming setInstanceFollowRedirects is already set to False, how do I know that Java skipped this URL because I was redirected? I need to know that so that it wont proceed to the test where it does not supposed to go?